# What is the default queue size and max concurrent connections/requests supported by kestrel?

Tags: kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I am reading that kestrel theoretically supports unlimited concurrent connections.

1. Is there a default value of the max number of concurrent connections and requests?
2. If the value goes beyond then is there some kind of queue and if so then what is the queue size for conndctions/requests?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a default value of the max number of concurrent connections?

No, it is infinity.

> If the value goes beyond then is there some kind of queue and if so then what is the queue size?

If configured, it will start to reject connections, it won't queue them.

I assume you meant to ask about connections and not requests? For requests we have https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ConcurrencyLimiter/

Comment: And what is the cap on number of requests?

Comment: There is no cap on the number of requests. You can configure limits to your liking.

Comment: Isn't it limited by the number of threads in the thread pool. Is there anyway to calculate this?

Comment: The threadpool doesn't have a limit and there's no way to calculate your theoretical maximum other than by measuring based on your acceptable criteria (throughput, memory, latency etc)